# Testing expo app with jest, but test crashes because of experimental syntax

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo, babel-jest

Have gotten a syntax error about experimental syntax 'classProperties'.
have tried installing different versions of babel plugin, and alternating .babelrc file.
[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5anF.png)

> SyntaxError:
>   /Users/Jostein/Documents/jobb_Ovitas/projects/hunnor/node_modules/react-native/jest/mockComponent.js:
>   Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently
>   enabled (20:24):

Any solution or help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the plugin `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-propperties` as suggested in your babel config file ? What does your babel config file look like ?

Comment: The .babelrc is in the root directory with package.json  Content of .babelrc file:  {
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "babel-preset-expo"],
  "plugins":[
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
  ]
}

Comment: For tests, I usually use the preset `presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset']`, that has lots of babel dependencies, including the `'@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'`. Maybe using that preset instead of the other could solve your problem to run tests with jest ?

Comment: Still get the same errormessage

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, it could mean that babel doesn't understand how you create your class properties. Make sure that they are created as in the example given by the docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Answer (score 1):

Actually got an answer from the babel team:

Please use babel.config.json instead of .babelrc. .babelrc is meant for file relative config, searching .babelrc will stop once a package.json is seen. So the @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties is never applied to node_modules/react-native/jest/mockComponent.js because there is a package.json in node_modules/react-native.